# Uploading data to mysql database?

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I'm new to the coding world and also new to Python and have a question. We (group of 4) have a schoolproject and im in charge of making a module.

I've made a PDF to text module and the outcome is supposed to be uploaded to the database. I'm using mariaDB which is working with MySQL if im right. The database part is a task of another team member. So this guy made the end points and im supposed to upload.

I'm using the library "Requests - HTTP" and made something like this. Ill just send the whole thing:

The actual thing that I have a problem with starts with "payload" and ends with "    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))"

```
import pdftotext
import requests

url = "THE URL"


def main():
    with open("s2-ovenschotelauberginebloemkool-022020.pdf", "rb") as f:
        pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)
    text = "\n\n".join(pdf)
    bevat = text.split("Dit recept bevat")[1].split("Ingrediënten")[0]
    try:
        bevat = prettify(bevat.split("persoon")[1])
    except IndexError:
        bevat = prettify(bevat.split("personen")[1])
    if "1 persoon" in text:
        aantal_personen = "1"
    else:
        aantal_personen = prettify(text.split(" personen")[0].split("bevat")[1])
    bereiding = prettify(text.split("Bereiding")[1].split("\n\x0c")[0])
    ingredienten = prettify(text.split("Ingrediënten")[1]).split("Bereiding")[0]
    stap = text.split("STAP ")[1].split("\n")[0]
    output = {
        "Preparation": bereiding,
        "Ingredients": ingredienten,
        "Text": bevat,
        "Step": int(stap),
        "Persons": int(aantal_personen),
    }
    payload = {
        'PDFPath': 'C:/asdfjkasldfjkl;',
        'CommunityID': 'CID123456789994',
        'Populairity': '000000000000000000000000000000',
        'Preparation': bereiding,
        'BannerImageID': 'BID123456789011',
        'Text': bevat,
        'ReadTime': '00:05:00',
        'AverageRanking': '000000000000000000000000000000',
        'Likes': '000000000000000000000000000000',
        'Title': 'Lekker Bloemkool soep met weinig calorieen',
        'Step': int(stap),
        'Persons': int(aantal_personen),
        'Ingredients': ingredienten
    }
    headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
    for x in output.items():
        print(x)


def prettify(text):
    return " ".join(text.strip().replace("\n", " ").replace(r"\n", " ").split())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you have some other things to say about my code please do. I want to be better of course :D

Comment: What is the output you want to receive when running the code?

Comment: I actually want everything that is in output{} uploaded to the database. So basically what my other team member says. The output are supposed to be uploaded to the database and that's why where the payload starts doing his job.

Comment: `I'm using mariaDB which is working with MySQL if im right` - no, you are not right! Mariadb is a fork of mysql, not mysql! The two are increasingly divergent!